# Large matrices with a certain structure: how can one define where memory allocation is not needed?

Tags: arrays, r, memory

**Is there a way to create a 3D array for which only certain elements are defined, while the rest does not take up memory?**

Context: I am running Monte-Carlo simulations in which I want to solve 10^5 matrices. All of these matrices have a majority of elements that are zero, for which I wouldn't need to use 8 bytes of memory per element. These elements are the same for all matrices. For simplicity, I have combined all of these matrices into a 3D array, but if my matrices start to become too large, I encounter memory issues (since at matrix dimensions of 100*100*100000, the array already takes up 8 GB of memory).

One workaround would be to store every matrix element with its 10^6 iterations in a vector, that way, no additional information needs to be stored. The inconvenience is that then I would need to work with more than 50 different vectors, and I prefer working with arrays.

**Is there any way to tell R that some matrix elements don't need information?**

I have been thinking that defining a new class could help for this, but since I have just discovered classes, I am not sure what all the options are. **Do you think this could be a good approach? Are there specific things I should keep in mind?**

I also know that there are packages made to deal with memory problems, but that did not seem like the quickest solution in terms of human and computation effort for this specific problem.

Comment: Have you tried [slam package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html) and its `simple_sparse_array` ?

Comment: I would just use a list of sparse matrices (see package Matrix).

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need! I did not know about sparse arrays and matrices. Many thanks to you both